# Cant Execute java Jar from Php Exec() function?

Tags: java, php

Im trying to execute  a java Jar by PHP Exec() function.

```
 $encryptPass = exec('/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /Users/sadasda/Desktop/EncryptTest.jar test123');
```

However all i get in output is blank string. I have given full paths to java and Jar. What could i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that could be going on. Some are:

- The paths could be wrong.  (Don't discount the possibility of a silly mistake ... )
- There could be a bug in the Java app.  (Have you tried running the command with the same args from the command line?  Have you tried capturing the "standard error" stream from the `java` command in PHP?)
- The java app could be expecting something on its "standard input" stream ... rather than in the command arguments.
- The hardened OS could be blocking PHP from executing arbitrary external applications.  (For example, SELinux in enforcing mode, or AppArmor.)

Comment: im able to execute the jar from commandline successfully. My OS is MacOs. How to capture the standard error stream from the java command in PHP?

Comment: 1) I don't know (not a PHP person).  2) This suggests that the problem is not bullet point #2, and probably not #1.